# Hyphenation of -oriented when preceded by two words

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Which of these two is correct:

> (a) I have experience in data science-oriented programming languages.

or

> (b) I have experience in data-science-oriented programming languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyphenating compound adjectives with more than two parts... eg 'working life oriented' / 'working-life oriented' / ... / 'working-life-oriented'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350399/hyphenating-compound-adjectives-with-more-than-two-parts)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Confirmed it as a duplicate.