# When to hyphenate an adjective composed of an adjective followed by a noun

Tags: compound-adjectives

I find that many apps highlight phrases like "high level", insisting an hyphenation.  The highlighting is distracting.  Based on [this](https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/58695/grammar-questions-answered) page and [this](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen-in-compounds-with-high-low/) page, the hyphenation is needed when referring to "high-level information" but not for "high level of information".

I didn't quite follow the logic, but tried to stress test the logic anyway.  For example, "car lot" seems reasonable, as does "small car lot".  As does "small car repair lot" and "damaged small car repair intake lot".  I wouldn't hyphenate any of these.  Is the logic for hyphenation actually sound?  Can someone explain it in simpler terms and provide unequivocal examples?

Comment: Note the need for hyphens to distinguish a sweet shop-girl / a sweet-shop-girl **and** three hundred year-old trees / three hundred-year-old trees / three-hundred-year-old trees.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin.  Would I be correctly summarizing that cited Q&A as there is no hard and fast rule, but it depends on which words you want to gel together more tightly than others, making the hyphenation rule ambiguous for a long series of words like "damaged small car repair intake lot"?  I'm careful about drawing this conclusion because the pages cited in the question imply that there definitely is a rule that applies (even though I have a hard time extending the logic to more complex phrases).

Comment: Articles and prepositions can break up a long sequence of nouns. Rephrasing, "An intake lot for the repair of small cars." The 'damaged' can be omitted since that is implied by 'repair'.

Comment: You seem to have made up the example starting from "small car lot". Is that a small lot for cars, or a lot for small cars?

Comment: It's a contrived example.  I realize that a sentence can be restructured to avoid the need for a long string of nouns acting as adjectives.  I often do that, but this question is really about what hard (reliable) rule(s) apply (if any) in situations where one chooses not to do that.

Comment: In speech, the intonation can provide the intended meaning, and of course has no hyphens. But in writing the long string of nouns can be difficult to parse, or not look very fluent with so many hyphens. Structure the sentence with more care, or choose to make it awkward. We use a lot of articles and prepositions in English to link the parts of a sentence.

Comment: @WeatherVane Reasoned-enough advice to form "An Answer."

Comment: The overriding rule transcends grammaticality. Grice's maxim of manner (... avoid obscurity, ambiguity [and other writing that can be misconstrued by a proficient Anglophone]) should trump all else. Then 'avoid over-complexity'. So 'damaged small car repair intake lot' needs rephrasing, not judiciously punctuating. The tree examples need judicious punctuation.

Comment: See also [Is it correct to hyphenate with compound premodifiers ? If so, where is the hyphen ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/is-it-correct-to-hyphenate-with-compound-premodifiers-if-so-where-is-the-hyphe) and [Hyphenating compound adjectives with more than two parts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350399/hyphenating-compound-adjectives-with-more-than-two-parts).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think I've heard it expressed ironically as "eschew obfuscation"

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  In summary, the ultimate answer is that there are very few ways to show the nested grouping of a many-modifier phrase.  Basically, a short dash and long dash, and sometimes the use of dashes leads to grammatical errors.  So the ambiguity is hard to avoid and is best addressed by restructuring the phrase.

Comment: The em-dash — and the en-dash – are different from the hyphen - (and have very different uses, in general). — , – //// -.